how to test uwb (ultra wide band) in Android Studio?
I have virtual device Google Pixel 6 Pro on Andrroid Studio Emulator but uwb is not showing. Any one have idea how to test uwb in Android studio and on which virtual device i can test uwb in Android studio?
https://i.sstatic.net/303vXUlD.png

It is not possible to use UWB with an emulator. You need a physical device that supports UWB.

It works from Android 12 onwards, and in the device settings, you can validate compatibility with UWB as shown in the image. Currently, I am testing a Blackview BV8900Pro that comes with a UWB beacon as a button-type accessory. The manufacturer does not provide an SDK, and they recommend using Google's API. So far, I have not been able to find another use case to create an application with this type of UWB beacons.
https://technotrend.substack.com/p/blackview-bv8900-pro-uwb-tag-teardown
BV8900Pro
